catastophic failure reinstall ubuntu 22.04 need permissions to add files to thunderbird client
i have reinstalled ubuntu and need to add address book and calender files/folders to the thunderbird (hidden) folder.
I see all hidden folders now, and am the physical owner and administrator of the machine, but it does not see me as "root" for purposes of modifying permissions so i can copy files into the thunderbird install.
I am a mid level person where it comes to ubuntu experience, and as well, if I may, I am not well and just had major surgery.
my questions, please:

is there an easy gui based way to do this?

if not, how, please, DO i do this so i only change root permissions on the one folder I need to (I don't want to make the whole machine less secure although i don't recall this issue on my previous ubuntu install on this same machine).


thanks in advance for all help!
neil

ps thunderbird import utility does not work


All your user files from thunderbird (mailboxes, server configurtion, etc. live under a hidden folder .thunderbird in your personal directory. You do not need to be root to copy files there. 2) If the system does not "see" you as root, then consult the person who installed your system. There is at least one user account that has root permissions on an Ubuntu system, that of the first user created on the system.


thank you. i see all the hidden folders, but i cannot change permissions as the message is always that I am not the owner of the files.

ps i AM  the person who installed it. hence my question here. i don't have anyone else to consult with.again,thanks.
